# Why doesn't $e^x$ have an inverse in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Why doesn't $e^x$ have an inverse in the complex plane? Can someone please clarify it?

Comment: Hint: $e^{2\pi i} =e^{0}$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among reals, only $0$ has the property that $e^0 = 1$, but among complex numbers, there are many $z$ such that $e^z=1$, for example, $2\pi i$, $4\pi i$, $6\pi i$ etc. But since $e^{z+w} = e^z*e^w$, you could add any of those numbers to any exponent $w$ and the value of $e^w$ doesn't change. Therefore $e^w$ is not one-to-one and so cannot have an inverse.

Answer (score 4):

Here comes the overkill: by [Great Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), any analytic function with an essential singularity at infinity takes every complex value, with at most one exception, an infinite number of times. $e^z$ clearly has an essential singularity at infinity.

Comment: That is most certainly not true. How about $f(z)=z$? (You're quoting big Picard, not little Picard, so you want a non-polynomial to get an essential singularity at $\infty$.)

Comment: @mrf: many thanks, now fixed.